# Python makefile pipeline using Ruffus

Tags: python, makefile, pipeline, ruffus

I am trying to pipeline multiple scripts with python framework using Ruffus.

I have multiple .cpp and .h files being called from my main.cpp file.

My makefile runs perfectly well in shell.

How can make a python based pipeline using Ruffus which can call and compile my script?

My makefile looks like this:

```
CC = g++ -std=c++0x -Wall
CFLAGS = -c -I /
LFLAGS = -L /

all: main

main: main.o 
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) main.o -o ./HELLO

main.o: main.cpp
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) main.cpp

clean:
rm *.o
```